# Apply class to numbers belonging to a sequence php photo grid

Tags: php

I' trying to apply a class third item in a row in a php photo grid output.

For instance

```
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
9 10 11
```

i would want to apply a class to the number 2, 5, 8, 11 and so on...

If the variable $i stores the number how can I check with php to see if it is part of that sequence using an if statement

Answer (score 0):

if $foo % 3 == 2

% is the modulus operator, which returns the remainder after division.

You want every 3rd item, hence % 3, but you are starting at 0 instead of 1, so you need to compare to 2 instead of 0.

edited to work on 2/5/8 instead of 3/6/9

Comment: Please see changes in my tittle. I dont want multiples of three since the output starts from the number 0

Answer (score 0):

When you say `$i` stores the number, do you refer to the `key` or `value`?

You can use the [modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulus) operator to find the remainder from a division operation.

In this case, assuming $i refers to the key:

```
// If the number's key can be divided by 3 without remainders (i.e. 3, 6, 9, 12, etc)
if ($i % 3 == 0) {
    // apply class
}
```

Comment: Please see changes in my tittle. I dont want multiples of three since the output starts from the number 0

Comment: I understand, this is why I asked whether `$i` refers to the `key` or `value`.

What is your code for creating the line break on every 3rd row?

Comment: It refers to the value. I'm using for ($i=0; $i<$j; $++)

Comment: OK. You could do one of three things:

1) Create an extra variable that increments alongside `$i`, which can be checked with the modulus statement

2) Start `$i` at 1, and when echoing the output, use `$i - 1`

3) Use the answer provided by vincent kleine

Answer (score 0):

" I dont want multiples of three since the output starts from the number 0 "
So then you could use this?

```
if (($i+1) % 3 == 0) {
//do something you'd do for the third item
}
```